# Ways of devices to communicate to other devices wirelessly

Tags: wireless, contiki-os

I am a programmer and I am trying to figure out a way to get information from wireless devices to gather information from for example I have a device(toy car) I would like to get information(speed, distance it run, etc and the information is available on the vehicle) from it.

> "What are the ways to get wireless information from the device? and
>   possibly the resource?"

Please note it's all still under development so I have nothing concrete. Sorry if the question is vague it's pretty hard for me to explain since this is not my profession(just willing to learn).

Comment: Huh? He has a toy car and he wants to know an easy way to wirelessly control it or get data back from it. You could bang this out in about 20min with an econotag and Contiki. People shouldn't close stuff just because they don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the [Econotag](http://www.redwirellc.com/store/node/1) and [Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/) operating system --- these are very easy ways for programmers to get involved with wireless systems.

Answer (score 0):

The least expensive method is to use IR Emitter detector pair for short range just as these low cost Helicopters use for remote control.  Make sure to use error detection in your link.

Ther are a variety of speeds supported that depend on power and range you need.  30m is a  practical limit with a good design and IR daylight blocking filters built-in and extra added if necessary. (  special dark plastic like in VCR Rx.)

Many duplicate answers for IR you can search and find.